# xsl transformation - tree xml to plain field-value xml

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

i want to automaticly process by xslt this xml by example, field and values must be dynamicly parsed, not hardcoded:

```
<root>
<field1>value1</field1>
<field2>value2</field2>
</root>
```

to this:

```
<items>
<field>field1</field>
<value>value1</value>
<field>field2</field>
<value>value2</value>
</items>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <items>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="firstElement" select="replace(name(),'([0-9])','')"/>
    <xsl:param name="SecondElement" select="replace(text(),'([0-9])','')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$firstElement}">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="{$SecondElement}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `name()` function to get the name of a current element.
For example, it will return `'field1'` if `.` is `<field1>`.

So corresponding part of template would be

```
<field><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></field>
<value><xsl:value-of select="." /></value>
```